# Vaadin 13 UI Components keeps reloading when deployed in Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, vaadin-flow

I'm trying to deploy a Vaadin 13 app on Google App Engine. Of course I added the appengine plugin on pom.xml and appengine-web.xml on WEB-INF.

When I run this code:

`mvn appengine:run`

it works expected when viewed on `localhost:8080`.

However, when I deployed it on Google App Engine:
`mvn appengine:deploy`

Screens displays as expected, but most components doesn't work and keeps reloading (Please see chatbot tab on http://tricera-chatbot.appspot.com/chatPage)

I created this using HTML + base Vaadin 13 starter as skeleton.

I also tried to deploy the actual Beverage App starter from Vaadin site, and it behaves the same when deployed on App Engine (UI components unusable)

Answer (score 0):

Posted this same question in Vaadin forum and someone answered:

> Google App Engine does not support sticky sessions and will route HTTP requests to random servers which do not necessarily have an up-to-date version of the HTTP session for the user. Because of this, it won't work as the UI state is store in the HTTP session.

This sounds like GAE doesn't support Vaadin13. I'm still looking for workarounds (aside from switching platforms) and will keep you updated for future viewers.

source: [Vaadin 13 Forum](https://vaadin.com/forum/thread/17657225/components-keeps-refreshing-vaadin-13-deployed-on-google-app-engine)